# Kernel module is removed successfully although warning message 'not found"

Tags: c, linux, unix, kernel, kernel-module

Yesterday I installed a very simple kernel module in my embedded Linux system. "hello.ko".
When I install this module to our system, it's normally:

```
#insmod hello.ko
    Initing kernel module
#
#lsmod
hello 638 0 - Live 0xf628f000
```

But when I remove this kernel module, **It can be removed normally but rmmod notice 'hello.ko' not found**

```
# rmmod hello
Cleaning kernel module
rmmod: module 'hello' not found
#lsmod <------------------- already be removed
#
# uname -a
# Linux SWITCH 2.6.32 #8 Thu Jun 23 20:34:48 KST 2016 ppc GNU/Linux
```

**It's very strange. Could anyone explain for me why 'hello.ko' is removed but there's log 'rmmod module not found'?**

The following are source code of hello.ko

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/config.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
int init_module(void)
{
    printk (KERN_EMERG "Initing kernel module\n");
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk (KERN_EMERG "Cleaning kernel module\n");
}

MODULE_DESCRIPTION ("Kernel function replacement module");
MODULE_AUTHOR ("DASAN Networks Inc.");
MODULE_LICENSE ("GPL");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few things in my opinion `__init` and `__exit` macros and `module_init` and `module_exit` macros, try with:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
static int __init init_example(void)
{
    printk (KERN_EMERG "Initing kernel module\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit cleanup_example(void)
{
    printk (KERN_EMERG "Cleaning kernel module\n");
}

module_init(init_example);
module_exit(cleanup_example);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION ("Kernel function replacement module");
MODULE_AUTHOR ("DASAN Networks Inc.");
MODULE_LICENSE ("GPL");
```

Comment: Have you tried changing names `init_module` and `cleanup_module` to something different ? I am receiving `redefinition` errors as is it now. Without it, it works on clean buildroot-based env on arm.

Comment: Also, are you using `busybox` based `rmmod` ? Maybe try with gnu rmmod (not sure how should I call it). I had some issues with `busybox` replacements sometime and often problems were solved just by replacing them in the `buildroot` by heavier standard tools.

Comment: You're right, I am using rmmod of busybox.
But my embedded system use rmmod of busybox. I cannot use another rmmod (Of course, I already changed name)